# "bash" command runs scripts in version 3.2, not 4.4

Tags: terminal, bash

Currently, in terminal, my default interactive shell is bash version 4.4. The OS ships with 3.2.

If I want to run a script (e.g., `my_script.sh`) using bash version 4.4, I can source it (`source my_script.sh`) or type it into my terminal directly. Though, in each case the script runs in my current shell.  I can also give a script execute permissions and run it as a command, allowing the shebang to control which version of bash to use.

However, the **command** `bash` continues to use version 3.2. For example, if I run `bash my_script.sh`, the script will be executed in a new shell (which I want), but the older version of bash will be used (3.2). Similarly, if I just run `bash` with no argument, a new shell opens up using version 3.2 (recall, if I open a new window or tab in terminal, it uses my default shell, bash v. 4.4. The problem here is what happens when I use the command `bash`).

I've added the path to bash 4.4 on my machine (`/usr/local/bin/bash`) to my `PATH` variable in `.bash_profile`, and it's not being overwritten somewhere else (`echo $PATH` gives the expected result: the very first path is `usr/local/bin/bash`). I expected this to change the behavior of the command `bash`

I can use a workaround, by setting an alias (`alias bash4='/usr/local/bin/bash'`), but I don't have to use an alias for bash 3.2, or for upgraded versions of, e.g., python or R.

Is there something I'm missing? Is the alias solution the only option here?

#### EDITS

in response to comments:

`SHELL` is `/usr/local/bin/bash`, which is unsurprising, since that's my default login shell.

`type -a bash` is interesting...

```
bash is /bin/bash
bash is /usr/local/bin/bash
bash is /bin/bash
bash is /usr/local/bin/bash
bash is /bin/bash
bash is /usr/local/bin/bash
bash is /bin/bash
bash is /usr/local/bin/bash
```

My entire PATH is a mess, which may be the source of this problem.

```
/usr/local/bin/bash:/Users/coltrane/Programming/Unix_Workbench/Code/Commands:/usr/local/bin/bash:/Users/coltrane/Programming/Unix_Workbench/Code/Commands:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Applications/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Users/coltrane/Programming/Unix_Workbench/Code/Commands:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Applications/anaconda/bin:/Users/coltrane/Programming/Android_Development/sdk/platform-tools:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Applications/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Users/coltrane/Programming/Unix_Workbench/Code/Commands:/usr/local/bin/bash:/Users/coltrane/Programming/Unix_Workbench/Code/Commands:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Applications/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Users/coltrane/Programming/Unix_Workbench/Code/Commands:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Applications/anaconda/bin:/Users/coltrane/Programming/Android_Development/sdk/platform-tools:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Applications/anaconda/bin:/Users/coltrane/Programming/Android_Development/sdk/platform-tools:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin
```

unrelated problem with my path, i had inadvertently repeated `$PATH` in one line of my `.bash_profile`, (PATH=$PATH::$PATH) causing unwanted duplication

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Please share the output or running `type -a bash` and `echo $SHELL`.

Comment: Please post the output of `echo $PATH`.  The default bash is found in `/bin/bash` and I'm betting it comes before the path to bash v.4.

Comment: @Alan nope. The only use of "bash" in $PATH is /usr/local/bin/bash, though it repeats many times... editing...

Comment: I mis-typed.  Bash is found in `/bin`.  Confirm this by typing `which bash`.  But we still need to see your path.

Comment: @Allan ahh, yes, `/bin` is in there multiple times, and I understood it should stay there. I put the path to bash 4.4 at the very beginning to solve this, though.

Comment: `/bin` is only in there once.  You have `/usr/local/bin` which is another directory altogether.

Comment: @Allan `/bin` as an entire path is actually in there 4 times (a search for `:/bin:` in the path I posted shows 4 matches). This is a result of an unrelated duplication of PATH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error here is that the first path in `PATH` was to the bash executable, instead of to the directory that **contains** the bash executable. For readers with similar problems: double check to make sure any path you're adding to your `PATH` variable resolves to a directory, not to a file.

#### Problem:

I had added the following to my `.bash_profile`:

`PATH=/usr/local/bin/bash:$PATH`

`/usr/local/bin/bash` is not a directory. It's a file (well, a symbolic link to a file). So, regardless of placing it at the very beginning of `PATH`, the command `bash` will not find an executable file named `bash` inside any directory in `PATH` until it gets to `/bin`.

#### Solution:

In `.bash_profile`, setting

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Solves the problem. Now the command `bash` finds the executable inside `/usr/local/bin` before it gets to `/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use bash 4.4 as your default shell do the following:

1. rename the `/bin/bash` file to something else (`bash3` for example)

   ```
   sudo mv /bin/bash /bin/bash3
   ```
2. create a symlink from your `/usr/local/bin/bash` to `/bin/bash`

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/bash /bin/bash
   ```

Now, anytime you open a shell it will open the 4.x version of bash and if you ever need to run bash v3.x, simply invoke `bash3`.

Comment: Just to clarify, bash 4.4 already is my default shell. Any time I open a shell it already opens the 4.x version of bash. But when I'm in my default shell, if I enter `bash`, it opens a new shell using version 3.2 and `bash my_script.sh` runs `my_script.sh` in a new shell using version 3.2.

Comment: `bash 4.4` is your interactive shell.  Because of your path, any subshells are 3.x   This solution makes certain you're using 4.4 first.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It looks like your solution would work (+1), but I ended up deciding to fix my path instead of adding a link that might confuse me later. Your comments on my question above helped me recognize what I should have seen from the beginning: `/usr/local/bin/bash` is not a directory, so it's meaningless to add it to my `PATH` variable. And, fyi, any subshells were 4.4 previously, it's just using the command `bash` that wasn't working as expected (because of my path error).

Comment: I had appropriately set my default shell as `/usr/local/bin/bash`, which is why shells (and subshells) were 4.4, *except* when using the `bash` command.

Comment: Is this really safe? That messes with SIP protected Apple binaries that are, apart from being outdated – creating one reason for the OP problem –, also Apple patched and God knows how twisted/patched up by Apple. That means this quick & 'dirty' hack can and probably will cause quite unforeseen problems down the road. Apple delivers patch for bash. What then? Big update rolls in, almost nothing is documented as usual, symlink gets overwritten. Bash versions might differ in unsuspected ways. I'd consider this only if nothing but SecUpdates come in, where patches to bash are probably doumented.

Comment: @LangLangC - Apple isn't going to do anything with bash since versions 3.3 and later switched licensing from BSD to GNU.  GNU requires you make *your* source code available if you include code in your product; BSD doesn't.  This is why you won't see bash 4.4 come bundled with macOS.

Comment: You are right, partially. GPL-fright *requires* Apple to patch and backport on the old branch. That is exactly why I do not trust this method. Been years since I tried OS darwin but I never reproduced a build that was identical with what Apple shipped. & I never completely tested either. Apple bash is in my view a black box better left completely untouched. Need new? Use new, excusively & as cleanly as possible. Sane defaults, clean $PATH, fullpath, etc. –– Meaning: have you a reference for a test/review that asserts that `mv bash4 /usr/bin/` is dsafe & survives Mojave updates cleanly?

Comment: Thing is, I don't upgrade in place.  I backup, wipe and install clean.

Comment: You do that, I prefer that, the majority probably not. But I was talking *updates* not *upgrades*. I doubt you clean-install on every point update or even less so on security updates? –– With the above method one needs to at least check after every update that bash hasn't been touched…

Comment: I apply every update that comes out and I've yet to have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not instruct the script explicitly to do your exact bidding?

Do not start it with

```
#!/bin/sh
```

or whatever your shebang is.

But try as the first line of your bash script

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
```

---

If the problems originates from trying to run

> When executing a bash script with the command bash my_script.sh, the shebang is treated as a comment. The shebang is only interpreted if I give my_script.sh execute permissions and run it as a command.

Then it's till possible to force your will without a cleaned up PATH environment (although it's still recommended to clean that up) with using absolute paths:

When executing a bash script with the command `/usr/local/bin/bash my_script.sh`

But for those cases an alias to the full path bash might come in handy…

Comment: When executing a bash script with the command `bash my_script.sh`, the shebang is treated as a comment. The shebang is only interpreted if I give `my_script.sh` execute permissions and run it as a command.

Comment: LangLang, that's a general principle re: when a shebang is interpreted vs. treated as a comment, not a problem I'm having :), but yes, the absolute path to the correct version worked before I fixed the path variable (and the alias to make it more convenient)